# how to find dimensions(length,width,height) of area when captured by camera?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-camera

I stuck at one point where i want to do this,
Wanna Take photo of area i want to find the dimensions of. For example, fridge cavity. With the photo it will display the measurements.(length.width.height)
                                                                                               or another example..just i take a photo of empty bedroom by camera,now how to find the exact dimensions(length,width,height).

Please help me guys,any link or any example would be very useful..
thanks in advance

Comment: You want to find the dimensions of what? The area like empty bedroom, etc.????

Comment: yes i want to find the the dimensions i.e length,width,height..example fridge,washing machine,wall,bedroom etc...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find the scale of the camera setup and then you could prob do it, but it would be under very certain conditions.

Why? Because of various scale issues. All of these issues will effect the applications ability to calculate any dimension of items in pictures you take:

1. Your Camera DPI / Pixels
2. The distance from the object.
3. The scale between real world object and how they appear on the camera.

This means you need to understand all of these properly and take them into account when you develop your program. For example:

1. A 4x2 wood piece picture from 2 feet is different to a 4x2 picture from 4 feet.
2. A 4x2 picture in a one camera is different to a 4x2 picture in another camera.

The distance matters a lot as say a 1 meter log from 10 meters will be much larger in the picture of the exact same log from 50 meters. How will the app know how to measure the real log size? only by proper calibration and taking photos under strict constrains.

You need to do some calibration and play round with it, and even then you would always have to take the picture from a given distance to really convert well.
(unless they will one day have two cameras or a 3 dimensional camera to measure the z..)

Comment: hello dory thanks for the answer...but on first priority i want the dimensions only i.e length,width,height of an area which i captured..dont care for the distance from the object...so please help to find the dimensions...

Comment: you want the height and width of an object you took the photo of, right?

Comment: yes exactly you are rite.i want the length,width,height of an object.